# Convert integer to float range, but range is reversed

Tags: math, floating-point, int, range

I need to convert one integer to a float, within a specific range that is ordered in reverse.

```
//if (int) value >= 1 && value <= 16,777,216
    //result = convert(value)

//if value = 1
    //result = 0.010 167 772 160
//if value = 16,777,216
    //result = 0.010 000 000 000

//convert() = ???
```

I'm stumped on figuring out the formula for convert(). Anyone?

Comment: Do you know how to do it if the range *wasn't* reversed?

Comment: sadly, no.  i'd just reverse the list then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just linear interpolation, can try this (it's not exacly, but close). What's problem you try to solve?

```
double convert( int x ) {
    return 0.01 + ( 16777216 - x ) * 0.00000000001;
}
```

Comment: this look promising. the problem is converting a stacking order or zDepth from 1 to 16 million into XNA's spriteBatch zdepths of 1.0 to 0.000 000 000 000 001.

Comment: just tested it:1 = : 0.01016777215
54,279 = : 0.01016722937
1,345,612 = : 0.01015431604
16,777,216 = : 0.01